# Java/Swing Save input to a file from multiple JTextField

Tags: java, swing, file

i'm trying to code a frame that get from the user a bunch of parameters and save them into a csv file and then redirect to a new frame that run a simulation, the problem is used a for loop to generate easily the text fields however i don't know how to write the event listener that retrive the data from all the text fields ,here's the code:

```
       private void ZoneTexte(String texte,JPanel pan) {
       JLabel label=new JLabel();
       label.setText(texte);
       JTextField text = new JTextField(20);
       pan.add(label);
       pan.add(text);
   }
   /**
    * 
    */
   private void SaveParam() {
       String [] param= {"Nom Milieu","ProbaRoche","ProbaHerbe","Qherbe","DistCaractHerbe","FacteurHerbe","RayonLac","ProfondeurMaxLac","SigmaLac"};
       JLabel label=new JLabel();
       label.setText("Définir vos propres paramètres de simulation:");
       EditPanel.add(label);
       for(String s:param) {
           JPanel pan1= new JPanel();
           ZoneTexte(s+" :",pan1);
           EditPanel.add(pan1);
       }
       JButton save=new JButton();
       save.setText("Enregistrer et démarrer la simulation");
       EditPanel.add(save);
       save.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }
           });
   }
   [The file format that i desire is this][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, you need to use a structure like a Map to keep a reference to each TextField. Then in your listener, you will parse your memory structure so that filling your csv.

```
// Somewhere in your init class
var fieldsMap = new HashMap<String,TextField>();

// In ZoneTexte method
fieldsMap.put(texte,text);      

// In your listener
var value = mapField.get("ProbaRoche").getText();
```

Perhaps, use a key unique for the field that can be used in different location of your code.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Keep the text fields in a list and iterate it when saving.

```
 List<JTextField> fieldList = new ArrayList <>() ;

...
    EditPanel.add(pan1)
    fieldList.add(pan1);
}

 save.addActionListener(e -> {
        for (JTextField field : fieldList) {
             file.writeString(field.getText); // however you want to write it 
        } 
 }
```

Comment: Thank you it worked,however it randomly scattered the text fields they're no longer in order and the label are hidden now, i'm new to swing and it's really hard for me to understand why things doesn't workout or not the way that i desire .